# How to get SharedPreferences data size, Is it possible?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences for saving JSONArray, and then using it when i have no connection to the internet. I should check size of saved data because i don't want any big data. I use clear method for that but i want to be sure about that with controlling size. My functions for saving & loading & clearing ;

```
public static void saveJSONArray(Context c, String prefName, String key, JSONArray array) {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, array.toString());
    editor.commit();
}

public static JSONArray loadJSONArray(Context c, String prefName, String key) throws JSONException {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    return new JSONArray(settings.getString(key, ""));
}

public static void clearPrefs(Context c, String prefName){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

This functions work properly. There is no problem. But i need one more function which returns the size of all data. I investigated it but could not find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you shouldn't cache data using 'SharedPreferences', you must cache them using files, in your app cache directory!

Comment: What kind of files? Give me more information about that please? @MoshErsan

Comment: "What kind of files?" -- since you have JSON, one might imagine that a JSON file would be appropriate.

Comment: So you say that i should save json file to my internal or external storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the string to bytes, and then get the length of bytes:

```
String data = array.toString();
byte[] byteArray = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
long size = byteArray.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

see this code:

```
public void cacheData(String data, String name) throws IOException {

    File dataFile = new File(getCacheDir(), name.concat(".json"));
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(dataFile));
    objectOutputStream.writeUTF(data);
    objectOutputStream.close();

}

public String readData(String name) throws IOException {

    File dataFile = new File(getCacheDir(), name.concat(".json"));
    if (!dataFile.exists()) {
        return null;
    }

    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(dataFile));
    String data = objectInputStream.readUTF();
    objectInputStream.close();

    return data;
}

public long getDataLength(String name){

    File dataFile = new File(getCacheDir(), name.concat(".json"));
    if (!dataFile.exists()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return dataFile.length();
}
```

since we save your data using "UTF-8", the data length may differ from another encode like cp1256

Answer (score 1):

I used @AndyRes 's idea and create a function named **sizeOfSharedPrefs** ;

```
public static long sizeOfSharedPrefs(Context c, String prefName, String command){
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(prefName, 0);
    String data = settings.getString(command, "").toString();
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        byteArray = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArray.length;
}
```

It works fine with my other functions.